# How to calculate/decide impact factor of a new journal

Tags: journals, job, faculty-application, bibliometrics

I have published my paper in a new journal in our field. The reason for submitting for this journal was the editorial board which consists of some of the top professors from best global universities (including University of Cambridge, University College London, Technical University of Munich, etc.).

Now I am applying for a job which requires me to list the impact factor for all my publications. Since the journal has only two issues yet there is no impact factor. How should I deal with this issue?

Comment: Obligatory question: are you really sure that the journal isn't a predatory one, listing the names of top professors without their consent just to attract inexperienced authors?

Comment: Yes, it is indexed in IEEExplore and part of IEEE Communications Society. (Also it is not open access or does not have any fee associated to it)

Answer (score 5):

Deal with it honestly.  Say exactly what you said here.  "Since only two issues of the journal have been published, there is as yet no impact factor."

Comment: If the journal is SCI indexed a shorter way to say this would be simply "Impact factor pending."

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if Impact factor is important today as journals such as eLife, peeej or f1000 etc. Don't rely only on impact factor. However, such as is your case I personally feel two criteria are important. One is availability in SCI or SCI expanded index and the other is PubMed.

Comment: As this is a new journal, as explicitly stated by the OP, what do you think the ratings will be on the two you suggest?

Comment: OP must rely only on the impact factor as their job requires it (as terrible a metric it may be).